# android Navigation UI Component Memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, navigation, leakcanary, appcompatactivity

Just started getting to know memory leaks with Leak Canary so forgive me if I conflate or misunderstand anything.
Leak canary tells me there is a memory leak and I've narrowed it down to this line

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
    it,
    navController
)
```

nav controller is called and set to the variable like this

```
val navController = findNavController(this@PokemonDetailFragment)
```

and 'it' is my activity cast to app compat activity, full snippet looks like this:

```
    mainActivity = (activity as AppCompatActivity)
    mainActivity?.let {
        it.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navController = findNavController(this@PokemonDetailFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
            it,
            navController
        )
    }
```

I've tried three things, 1. Injecting the activity instead, 2. Setting activity as a global nullable variable and setting it to null in onDestroyView, and 3. tried using the NavigationUI.setupWithNavController instead of the setupActionBarWithNavController which takes a toolbar and the nav controller

```
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
        binding.toolbar,
        findNavController(this@PokemonDetailFragment)
    )
```

but none of these fix the issue.

Removing the first code block definitely removes the leak, however Leak Canary doesn't show the leak as being with a third party library and does say it's a variable in my code below is the heap dump

````
    ```
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: Local variable in native code
    │
    ├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
    │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
    │    Thread name: 'LeakCanary-Heap-Dump'
    │    ↓ HandlerThread.contextClassLoader
    ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
    │    Leaking: NO (InternalLeakCanary↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
    │    ↓ PathClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (InternalLeakCanary↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ Object[].[502]
    ├─ leakcanary.internal.InternalLeakCanary class
    │    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static InternalLeakCanary.resumedActivity
    ├─ com.sealstudios.pokemonApp.MainActivity instance
    │    Leaking: NO (FragmentContainerView↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
    │    ↓ MainActivity._binding
    ├─ com.sealstudios.pokemonApp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding instance
    │    Leaking: NO (FragmentContainerView↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ ActivityMainBinding.navHostFragment
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView instance
    │    Leaking: NO (View attached)
    │    mContext instance of com.sealstudios.pokemonApp.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    View.parent androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout attached as well
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.nav_host_fragment
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ FragmentContainerView.mKeyedTags
    │                            ~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ android.util.SparseArray instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ SparseArray.mValues
    │                  ~~~~~~~
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ Object[].[0]
    │               ~~~
    ├─ androidx.navigation.NavHostController instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ NavHostController.mOnDestinationChangedListeners
    │                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ CopyOnWriteArrayList.array
    │                           ~~~~~
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ Object[].[1]
    │               ~~~
    ├─ androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.mContext
    │                                            ~~~~~~~~
    ├─ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ContextThemeWrapper wraps an Activity with Activity.mDestroyed false
    │    ↓ ContextThemeWrapper.mBase
    │                          ~~~~~
    ├─ dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper wraps an Activity with Activity.mDestroyed false
    │    ↓ ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper.fragment
    │                                                  ~~~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.sealstudios.pokemonApp.ui.PokemonDetailFragment instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.sealstudios.pokemonApp.ui.PokemonDetailFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
    ​     key = 724affdf-d1ac-47ff-82b8-6907ced5b666
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 9052
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 4051

    METADATA

    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29
    Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
    LeakCanary version: 2.4
    App process name: com.sealstudios.pokemonApp
        Analysis duration: 14474 ms```
````

any help appreciated I just want to set the toolbar which needs an AppCompatActivity and then dispose of it properly or allow the system to do it

I'm using Hilt and found this not sure if its related although my heap does mention the ContextThemeWrapper - https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2070

Comment: Can you provide the code in findNavController and NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController ?

Comment: @D.Pereira these are navigation architecture component methods

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that PokemonDetailFragment was destroyed but is still being referenced somewhere. My thought was that the controller returned by findNavController is holding onto this reference

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get anywhere with this and setting it manually removes the memory leak

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private fun setActionBar() {
    binding.toolbar.outlineProvider = null
    binding.appBarLayout.outlineProvider = null
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar.apply {
        this?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        this?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` function.

Let's have a look at the code snippet below:

```
public static void setupWithNavController(@NonNull Toolbar toolbar,
        @NonNull final NavController navController,
        @NonNull final AppBarConfiguration configuration) {
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(
            new ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener(toolbar, configuration));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            navigateUp(navController, configuration);
        }
    });
}
```

As we can see, you are adding a listener to your `navController` which is a new instance of `ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener()`.

Because you do not remove the listener of the navController when the activity / fragment life cycle enters the Destroy state, this is most likely causing your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I strongly recommend to unset(nulling) every used object in the fragment, especially the bitmaps, in `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Here is my example:
    myBigBitmap = null;
    adapter = new MyAdapter(requireContext(), new String[0], new String[0], new Bitmap[0]);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
}
```

This is the only correct method. Working 100%.

Comment: i mention this in the post

Comment: Some gave a negative vote, but I wrote this because I tested this through memory behavior for a given process, through taskmanager. There are people who kick the ball on first contact.